# 1-OR-3-SAT is in P

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability, 3-sat

**1-OR-3-SAT**:

Input: 3-CNF formula $\varphi$

Question: whether there is an assignment $x$ such that in each clause there are one or three true literals.

I need to show that this problem is in $P$. I tried to construct a reduction from this problem to 2-SAT that is in $P$. What can I try here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

> Can you express the clause in modular arithmetic?